# WriteProfileString and ReadProfileString functions

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, ini

Is there a WriteProfileString support directly in C#? I do not want to use the unmanaged function from kernel32.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, as far as I know, .NET does not support INI files anymore.

In the .NET world, the INI file format has been widely replaced by XML, which is the new de-facto standard for configuration files (e.g. `app.config` files for which the .NET Framework provides support through the static `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class).

Comment: WriteProfileString generally goes to the registry, not a INI file.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725504%28VS.85%29.aspx. Despite that, I must concede that you're probably correct. However, my answer focuses on the topic of INI vs. XML because the question is tagged with `file-io` and `ini`. Furthermore, if this is about the registry instead of about INI files, I would see absolutely *no* reason for not using P/Invoke to the named API functions; probably the strongest argument against P/Invoke, namely platform independence, wouldn't be relevant in the first place.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have decided to just go the XML route to avoid calling using interop calls in managed code.